# Criar entity programaticamente e salvar no core data

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

Olá, queria saber como faço para salvar uma entity no core data programaticamente.

Tentei o seguinte procedimento:

**Passando parametro**

```
MatchCoreData().createEntity(name: "Partidas123")
```

**Func criando a entity(creio que esta faltando salvar no core)**

```
public func createEntity(name: String)
{

    // Create the entity
    var entities = Array<NSEntityDescription>();
    let model = NSManagedObjectModel()
    let entity = NSEntityDescription()


    if entities.count == 0
    {
        entity.name = name
        entity.managedObjectClassName = String(describing: Match.self)

        entities.append(entity)
        model.entities = [entity]

        saveContext()
    }


    for item in entities
    {

        if (item.name?.contains(name))!
        {
        }else
        {
            entity.name = name
            entity.managedObjectClassName = String(describing: Match.self)

            model.entities = [item]
            saveContext()

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu geralmente faço assim:

```
func saveTransaction(name: String, value: Decimal) -> Transaction {
    let context = CoreDataManager.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let tr = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Transaction", into: context)
    tr.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
    tr.setValue(value, forKey: "value")

    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch let saveErr {
        print("Failed to save transaction:", saveErr)
    }

    return tr as! Transaction
}
```

Onde `CoreDataManager` é um singleton que contém meu `NSPersistentContainer`.